# Memcached Settings for stopping key expiration

Tags: memcached

I want to know is there any way for Memcached to stop its LRU collection of keys so that i can find at what point the given memory allocated for memcached gets full.

I dont want memcached to flush the old keys when it goes out of space.

Comment: Are you asking for "I want to wait until the memcache is full and no new entries are accepted" ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the -M switch, and memcached will return an error when the memory is exhausted instead of removing items.

Example:

```
memcached -d -m 1000 -M
```

This runs memcached daemonized with maximum memory of 1000 MB.  It will return an error when the 1000 MB are consumed.